# Nodejs Express implicit middleware applied to all routes?

Tags: node.js, express

I wanted to know if Express would let me create a route middleware that would be called by default without me explicitly placing it on the app.get() arg list?

// NodeJS newb

```
var data = { title: 'blah' };

// So I want to include this in every route
function a(){
  return function(req, res){
    req.data = data;
  };
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: req.data.title });
};
```

I understand I can do `app.set('data', data)` and access it via `req.app.settings.data` in the route.  Which would probably satisfy my simple example above.

Comment: FYI function a() { return function() seems so unelegant to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function a(req, res, next){
  req.data = data;
  // Update: based on latest version of express, better use this
  res.locals.data = data;
  next();
};

app.get('/*', a);
```

See the examples on the [Express docs, Middleware section](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Comment: Thanks, pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: you would probably want to map this to app.all though,
to make sure its executed for post requests as well.

Comment: updated the answer to recommend `res.locals.data = data;` instead

Answer (score 4):

You can create a default way to call every view you have made without have to explicit create a new route for every new entry. Check out this following example:

```
app.get('/:viewname', function(req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.viewname, { viewname : req.params.viewname});
});
```

I hope it's you're looking forward.

Comment: This works and I like the idea of not writing lots of identical calls to render simple pages. Though, this converts 404s to 500s for pages not yet implemented. (newbie question, how to handle that case?)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
function my_middleware(req, res, next){
   req.data = data;

   if (something(res)) redirect('http://google.com'); // no access to your site
   next(); // go to routes

};

app.configure(function() {
   ...
   app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
   app.use(express.session());
   app.use(my_middleware);
   app.use(app.router);
   ...
}
```

In this case my_middleware is called when cookies and sessions are already available, but no routes are processed yet. Or you can even do it before session if you need it for some reason.